# How to get absolute path of a file

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get the absolute path to use as a static reference

```
<input type="file" onClick="getFilePath">

function getFilePath(e)
{
  console.log( e.target.files[0] );
}
```

but I'm getting only the name of the file..

for example if I need to open an image locally I need to provide the url

```
new ImageLayer({
            source: new Static({
              url: 'https://foo.bar.com/lorem/image.png',//Local path goes here
              projection: projection,
              imageExtent: extent
            })
          })
```

Comment: Why do you need absolute path of an uploading file? I believe you just cannot do this due to obvious privacy concerns.

Comment: Can you provide more info? You cannot get the actual path to the file on disk for security reasons.

Comment: I need to use it as static link to an API

Comment: What exactly does that mean? Please provide a concrete example.

Comment: But you can't use that link to access the file anyway, for obvious security reasons

Comment: then what's the solution

Comment: Are you talking about an uploaded file to your server, and its local path server side ?

Comment: yeah, kind of      .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, you have to serve the file first.

**Either** you do it by creating a persistent reference string with a unique URL that temporarily references to the in-memory blob object that lives in the Blob URL Store by using [URL.createObjectURL()](https://chrisrng.svbtle.com/using-url-createobjecturl)

**Or** going to your local directory and serve it using [http-serve](https://github.com/indexzero/http-server) then use the link as a path

```
localhost:8080/foo.txt
```

Comment: What does _"...,you have to serve the file first."_ mean? ... One can't, either before or after the file is selected.

Answer (score 0):

If it's the path of a file, it can be done easily with node.js
 like so...

```
const path = require('path')
   path.dirname('whatSoEver')
```

Comment: some browsers like mozilla has this **this.files[0].mozFullPath**

Comment: But anyways maybe you may want to check this help out
  [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15201071/how-to-get-full-path-of-selected-file-on-change-of-input-type-file-using-jav

Comment: `require` doesn't exist in browsers.